# How do you set GeoPy to one specific country, in Python? i.e. The UK

Tags: python, geopy

Im having trouble setting GEOPY to one country specifically. For example, when I use GEOPY to give me the Long/Lat co-ordinates for Glagow, it returns Glasgow in USA!

```
>>> print(location.address)
Potsdamer Platz, Mitte, Berlin, 10117, Deutschland, European Union
>>> print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
(52.5094982, 13.3765983)
```

Comment: Did you try to add ` UK` explicitly to your geocode?

Comment: yes i did thanks to no avail